# Performance Issues with Include in Entity Framework

Tags: json, entity-framework, repository-pattern, asp.net-web-api2, poco

I am working on a large application being developed using Repository Pattern, Web APIs, AngularJS. In one of the scenario, I am trying to retrieve data from a single lead which has relations with approx. 20 tables. Lazy loading is disable, so I am using Include to get the data from all the 20 tables. Now, here comes performance issue, if I try to retrieve single record, it takes approx. 15 seconds. This is a huge performance issue. I am returning JSON and my entities are decorated with DataContract(IsReference = true)/ Data Member attribute.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the generated SQL and you'll understand. Many Includes is *the* way to hit performance.

Comment: My tip for you to debug your application is to use something like Express Profiler to get the exact query that EF is creating and executing. Then you use a 2nd tool to analyze that executed query. I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Tool to execute that query with "Include Actual Execution Plan" selected.

That my preferred way of working with collecting data from database with EF. I've exposed several huge joins generated with EF with this method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The performance has been improved by Enabling Lazy Loading.

Answer (score 2):

Include is really nasty for performance because of how it joins.

See more info in my blog post here http://mikee.se/Archive.aspx/Details/entity_framework_pitfalls,_include_20140101

To summarize **the problem** a bit it's because EF handles Include by joining. This creates a result set where every row includes every column of every joined entity (Some contain null values).

This is even more nasty if the root entity contains large fields (like a long text or a binary) because that one get repeated.

15s is way too much though. I suspect something more is at play like missing indexes.

To summarize **the solutions**. My suggestion is normally that you load every relation separately or in a multiquery. A simple query like that should be 5-30ms per entity depending on your setup. In this case it would still be quite slow (~1s if you are querying on indexes). Maybe you need to look at some way to store this data in a better format if this query is run often (Cache, document, json in the db). I can't help you with that though, would need far more information as the update paths affect the possibilities a lot.